# How to update some columns of a table in Hive with the data of other table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to update data for some columns  in one table from another table.

For these three columns `cf_mng,cf_sds,cf_htg` in the table `cust_tabl` there is no data.

I want to update data for these three columns `cf_mng,cf_sds,cf_htg` of `cust_tabl` 
with the data of the three columns `cust_cd_cnt_1,cust_cd_cnt_2,cust_cd_cnt_3` of `custom_hist` table.

This table is having data from 201505 to 201509.

```
CREATE TABLE custom_hist( 
 cust_no varchar(20),    
 cust_cd_cnt_1 float,  
 cust_cd_cnt_2 float,  
 cust_cd_cnt_3 float,  
 cust_dt date,
 cust_name string) 
 PARTITIONED BY (yyyymm int);
```

This table is having data from  201403 to 201606.

```
CREATE TABLE cust_tabl(
cust_no string,  
cf_mng double,  
cf_sds double,  
cf_htg double,  
cust_loc string,  
cust_region string,  
cust_country string,
cust_reg_id smallint)
PARTITIONED BY (yyyymm int);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Join your tables by primary key and overwrite joined partitions. Check the primary key. The join cardinality should be 1:1 or 1:0 otherwise you should apply some `row_number` or `rank` or some aggregation like `max()` to limit rows after join:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;

insert overwrite table cust_tabl partition (yyyymm)
select 
      c.cust_no,
      coalesce(h.cust_cd_cnt_1,c.cf_mng) as cf_mng, --take history column if joined
      coalesce(h.cust_cd_cnt_2,c.cf_sds) as cf_sds, --take original if not joined
      coalesce(h.cust_cd_cnt_3,c.cf_htg) as cf_htg,
      c.cust_loc,  --original columns
      c.cust_region,
      c.cust_country,
      c.cust_reg_id,
      c.yyyymm     --partition is the last
  from cust_tabl c
       left join custom_hist h 
                 --assume this is the primary key:
                 on c.cust_no = h.cust_no and c.yyyymm = h.yyyymm;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however If I reinsert for all columns it will take lot of time since the table is very huge and has lot of columns. Could you please help me to update only those there columns by altering table or some other method. Thanks

Comment: I do not know the other efficient way than join these tables. Join is slow and will take 90% of the time required. Rewrite is not so slow, do not worry about it

Comment: If tables are big, you can add `distribute by yyyymm` at the end of the query to reduce pressure on reducers and also try to reduce `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` parameter to increase reducer parallelism.

Comment: Client is not agreeing for reinsert. Any alternative approach please.

Comment: If your version of Hive supports ACID Update or Merge you can try to use this feature. It will not be faster because you need to join the datasets anyway and rewrite table partitions files. One more possible approach is to limit partitions to be rewritten to only those that was joined and keep as is those not joined. Use subquery instead of table c: `(select * from cust_tabl where yyyymm in (select distinct yyyymm  from custom_hist)) c` In such way you will eliminate rewriting not updated partitions if they exist. But if there are no such or very few, additional subquery may reduce performance